# Using NodaTime How do I calculate the number of minutes between two datetimes while factoring in business hours and timezone?

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

The [NodaTime](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) library makes it much easier to work with dates and times but I can't figure out how to calculate the number of minutes between two dates while accounting for business hours and time zone using NodaTime. here's an example (note my start and end date are always stored as UTC, but the business hours can be any time zone):

```
Start: 2024-02-23T01:00:00Z
End: 2024-02-29T09:45:00Z
Business Hours: M-F 07:30:00 - 17:30:00 Eastern Standard Time (so either UTC−05:00 or UTC−04:00 depending on time of year)
```

Answer should be 2835 minutes I believe, thank you

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd avoid the time zone abbreviation - do you actually mean "Eastern Time" instead of EST? Or do you *always* mean UTC-5? Or something else?

Next, how do you want time zones to be accounted for in terms of time? If the business hours include (say) midnight to 3am, do you want that to count as 4 hours during a fall-back, and 2 hours during a spring forward, assuming both happen at 1am? What if the business hours are 01:30-10:00, and there's a fall-back from 2am to 1am... do we get count both occurrences of 01:30-02:00? Fundamentally, write *very* detailed reqs.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the reply! I corrected the EST thing above. In terms of the spring forward/fall back I would choose to ignore them if possible. The client is more interested in the total elapsed number of minutes between the two dates. Thank you. There's a reason most languages have a poor implementation of date/time, its complicated!

Comment: "Eastern Standard Time" doesn't depend on the time of year - "Eastern Standard Time" is *always* UTC-5 (unless you're using it as a Windows time zone ID, because the Windows time zone IDs are broken). But your statements of "I would choose to ignore them if possible" and "the client is more interested in the total elapsed number of minutes between the two dates" are contradictory. The elapsed number of minutes during business hours *absolutely* depends on spring forward / fall back, if business hours include "open very early in the morning"

Comment: Also: what does "Account for" mean, here? All the business hours during the period from start to end?

Comment: @JonSkeet Exactly, its the Windows Timezone Id I'm referring to (that's what I'm using to convert to/from UTC before looking into NodaTime). But you're right about spring forward/fallback, now that I think on it it must be part of the calculation. So say the end date is 2024-03-10T22:00:00Z then it would lose an hour in that calculation. So then is there a way in NodaTime to define a rule for time ranges to ignore during calculations when calling Period.Between()? Like if you could call a function returning a bool whether to count it or not? How would you tackle this? thanks again

Comment: But since I just had to do something similar: I resolved all the business hours to concrete utc instances in time, then did the calculation.

Comment: @Fildor yes counting all the business-open minutes between the two dates. Do you mind sharing what you wrote?

Comment: I'll try to, tomorrow. I cannot access right now. I also will need to rip out all the company-specific stuff...

Comment: "its the Windows Timezone Id" - it's worth being *really* clear about that in the question then, because it's completely against the normal meaning of "Eastern Standard Time". Periods in Noda Time operate on LocalDateTime/LocalDate, which don't have a concept of time zone; they're not really appropriate for this. But no, there's nothing like a predicate-based period either.

Comment: Fildor's approach sounds appropriate to me - with suitable caveats for "what do you want to do in weird cases like opening at 01:30".

Comment: While there's nothing in Noda Time to make this easier right now, I'm happy to at least think about how we could provide something. The tricky bit is not to over-index on one specific use case...